# s3 hadoop error: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsRegistry.newCounter

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet, hadoop2

I created credentials like as:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "ACCESS_ID");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "SECRET VALUE");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.NAME);
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
```

and Path

```
 Path path = new Path("s3a://<backet>/<directory>/my.parquet");
```

When tried to write parquet data:

```
   try (ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericData.Record>builder(path)
                .withSchema(avroSchema)
                .withConf(conf)
                .withCompressionCodec(SNAPPY)
                .withWriteMode(OVERWRITE)
                .build())
```

And following error occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsRegistry.newCounter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;J)Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/MutableCounterLong;
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.counter(S3AInstrumentation.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.counter(S3AInstrumentation.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.<init>(S3AInstrumentation.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:209)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:266)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:489)
at Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

There my dependencies:

```
org.apache.avro-1.8.2, org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-core-1.2.1, org.apache.parquet-parquet-hadoop-1.8.1, org.apache.parquet-parquet-avro -1.8.1, org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1, org.apache.hadoop-hadoop-aws -2.8.2
```

Do you know how resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsRegistry.newCounter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;J)Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/MutableCounterLong;
```

The `MetricsRegistry` class is part of the [`hadoop-common`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common)  library. You are missing it from the list of dependencies.
Make sure the version of this jar is same as that of the `hadoop-aws` jar.

Also, it is recommended to have same version for all the hadoop dependency jars.

**Update:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

You are trying to use Hadoop libraries to write to S3. In that case, Hadoop will attempt to use the local filesystem for creating temporary files. This being the Windows operating system, you would need the [`winutils`](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils).

1. Download the `winutils.exe` binary and other required files as per your Hadoop version from [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils).
2. Set the environment variable `%HADOOP_HOME%` to point to the directory where these binaries were installed.

**Read more:** [Hadoop2 - Windows Problems](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems)

Comment: thank you, i tried, but not help. Therefore I used s3n, and it works

Comment: Okay. But once you add the hadoop-common jar, this error should have been resolved. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: I got  org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z error, also I updated to 3.0.0,  it does not help

Comment: Do you know how can I resolve this? a3n is deprecated for this 3.0.0 version...

Comment: I set it like that, and set HADOOP_HOME like as  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\avalieva\\Downloads\\winutils-master\\hadoop-3.0.0");

Comment: Do you know how load data without hadoop instalation and without hadoop home setting? hadoob-core does not help

Comment: Sorry, I have  org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0 error, I deleted HADOOP_HOME, and I cannot add hadoop-core(another error occurred) :  conf.set("fs.s3.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
        conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key","key_id"); conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","key");
        conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");     conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.NAME);

Comment: Do you know what is needed?

Comment: These credentials workrked with s3n, but not with s2a

Comment: @ЭльфияВалиева I have updated the answer to solve the windows error.